# Can the :before and :after pseudo-elements inherit height from the parent element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, inheritance

I am wondering whether the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements can inherit the height from parent using the `inherit` value, without the actual element doing so?

Comment: Not sure about your use case, but if you just need :before/:after to have the same height as the parent element, then `height: 100%` in the pseudoelement works quite well.

Comment: @AdamLibuša you miss an important point here. The parent should be positioned relative and the psuedo absolute for this to work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. The only way that pseudo-elements can inherit values from the parent of their generating element is when the generating element itself is also inheriting from its parent.

This is because inheritance occurs from a parent to a child, one level at a time. For inheritance to work across several levels of descendants, *every descendant must inherit*.

As an example, consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.parent > .child:before, .parent > .child:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

This will not work because even though the pseudo-elements have values of `inherit`, the element generating them, that is, `.parent > .child`, does not inherit from `.parent`. Instead, they inherit the default value of `auto` for both properties.

In order for this to work you will need to have `.parent > .child` inherit as well:

```css
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.parent > .child {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}

.parent > .child:before, .parent > .child:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I know this question is fairly old, but I stumbled on it today. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html, the accepted answer isn't accurate:

> The `:before` and :after pseudo-elements inherit any inheritable properties from the element in the document tree to which they are attached.

I just tried inheriting width and it worked.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to clarify. I think it was too short and therefore it might have been confusing.

Comment: When I posed the question, I didn't understand how the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements worked. Take this situation: `divA > divB::after` - the intent of my question was to know whether `divB:after could inherit `divA`'s properties. In my phrasing of the question: _parent element_ referred to `divA` and _actual element_ referred to `divB`. I hope my question was interpreted in this manner.

Comment: thanks @BoltClock, it's much more clear now. AKG, i think your question was originally understood correctly, but all is more clearer now anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want **to use your `::before` pseudo-element to implement a background**  the trick is to make sure that you positioned your element `absolute` and his parent `relative`. Make also sure you set the width of the parent.

### Example

```
&__item {

    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
      
        &::before {
            content: "";
            background-color: red;
            background-size: 100%;
            
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Concerning these answers, I was just bumping into the aspect of transformation. It may resemble on inheritance; I hope it helps somebody.

Having this:

```
<div class="box">    
  <div class="frame"></div>
</div>
```

and this transformation for `frame`:

```
transform: rotate(10deg);
```

Then the `frame:before` and `frame:after` are also transformed. Yet they do not have the properties of `frame`, such as `width` and `height`, which is like explained above. Full example see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/chafpgwt/1/

On this fiddle, there are three nested squares, each rotated by 10 deg, but the transform definition is only set for the `frame`, not for `frame:after` neither `frame:before`.

It is a pitfall to think transformations also are not "inherited", as everything else is neither. The transformation has influence in another context.