# How do I make ::before fill the height?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="brokencss.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="datapoint">
    <span class="label">
        This is a test.
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(0,30,60);
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top:20px;
    color: rgb(250,240,250);
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    font-size: 35px;
}

.datapoint::before {
    content: ">>";
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
}

.datapoint {
    margin-top: 15px;
    max-width: 20em;
    background-color: red;
    height:100%;
}

.label {
    font-family:'Courier New';
    font-size:60px;
}
```

which is rendered like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX9ry.jpg

I want the black ::before block with the ">>" to fill the height of the .datapoint div but I can't find a way to do this. I've set height of both to 100% so I'm a bit confused as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: You could do something like this, but it's not very good solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ahuLwgsm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better solution rather than I've provided:

1. I made `::before` and `label` elements displayed `inline-block`.
2. I set `line-height` of the `label` element equals to `font-size`.
3. I set `line-height` of the `::before` element the same value.
4. Added `vertical-align: top;` to the `::before` element.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(0,30,60);
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top:20px;
    color: rgb(250,240,250);
    font-family: 'Verdana';
    font-size: 35px;
}

.datapoint::before {
    content: ">>";
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.datapoint {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 20em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.label {
    font-family:'Courier New';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datapoint">
        <span class="label">
            This is a test.
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Built on top of the fiddle created by Vladimir in his comment, which only needed the padding added. See this [fiddle illustrating a solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ahuLwgsm/1/).

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

The above CSS Will force the text to stay on one line as any new lines will not obey the padding right. I hope this helps.

The `position: absolute;` is what makes your element stretch height. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124953/can-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-inherit-height-from-the-parent-elemen) for more about :before pseudo element.