# CSS before inherit height from it's element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

So I'm trying to build a pop-up block for switching the language on a website.

Due to the design having certain shadows, I need to build the shadow separately from the pop-up block itself. so I wanted to position it under the block using the ::before pseudo-element.

Now I need it to inherit the height from the element i'm using it on. Right now, there are three language options in the block, but I can't use static height since maybe in the future they will want to add more languages.

here is my code snippet:

```css
.l-pop {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07), 0px 1.67px 33.42px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0503), 0px 0.89px 17.87px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0417), 0px 0.5px 10.02px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.035), 0px 0.27px 5.32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0283), 0px 0.11px 2.21px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0197);
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.l-pop::before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  /* height: 100% */
}
```

```html
<div class="language__pop-up l-pop">
  <div class="l-pop__item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="l-pop__item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="l-pop__item">
    <img src="" alt="">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The weird part is that it works for the width, giving the ::before element a width of 150px, but not for the height.

Is there a way for the ::before pseudo-element to take it's height from the initial element?

I tried height: inherit and height: 100%, none of which worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the :before and :after pseudo-elements inherit height from the parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124953/can-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-inherit-height-from-the-parent-elemen)

Comment: What is it about the shadows that requires something other than `box-shadow`, or `filter: box-shadow()`? If we know what the specific problem is, we may be able to offer better answers.

Comment: The idea is that I also need to create an arrow above the block which I did by creating another block using ::after, rotating it 45 degrees and positioning it with the angle a few pixels on top of the main block. Now the whole construction needs to have same shadows, but if I put the shadow on the main block, it will overshadow the arrow. This is why I need all three elements separately, in order to position them on top of eachother without overshadowing anything.

Comment: That sounds possible, could you add an image showing the desired end-result, just for clarity?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution but I already solved the issue by adding position to the before element.

Comment: If you're still curious or might have some other useful suggestions, this is the result that I'm trying to achieve: 
https://imgur.com/a/2tgAVhI

Comment: I have a couple of ideas I'd like to play with, but I won't be able to answer until the morning (it's a little late here, in the UK, for turning the computer back on unfortunately).

Comment: Fair enough, I'm on it though.

Comment: Well, that took several hours to work through; but if it's of any use to you, there's this: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/81g97ydr/ (though I did have to add a wrapper element - called `.l-pop__clip-shadow`, because I don't really understand BEM - in order to allow a `drop-shadow()` to be used along with `clip-path()`).

Comment: This is exactly the solution I came up with after all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was adding position:absolute to the before element.

Comment: You should put actual code in your answer for others to view. i.e. use the Copy Snippet to Answer button and update that with the fix so it is easily seen by a comparison

Answer (score 0):

Its working for width because you set element having class `language__pop-up l-pop`  width: 150px but you make height: auto, that why its not working for height.Try to set height in px as you set the width for element having class `language__pop-up l-pop`

Comment: One more option is to set class "language__pop-up l-pop" height: -webkit-fill-available; .                               
Once the before element removes, original container height resets.

Comment: This would work for static height, yes. But I want to use dinamic height specifically, to allow the user to add more options to the block in the future.

Anyway, I already solved it, by adding position to the before element and using height: 100%.